# When I upgraded WebStorm to 2017.2 and Ionic plugin to 3.5.0, it seems not support my Ionic v1 project any more

Tags: ionic-framework, webstorm, upgrade

The whole `www` folder are in gray in the project tree pane on left side of the IDE.

All the keywords in `.js` script files are not grammatically colored any more.

So are the `.html` template files. Even the `<ion-content>`, `<ion-list>` directives can't be identified.

It seems not support Ionic v1 any more. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actual ticket (says fixed for **2017.2.1**): https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-27898

*Not sure what exactly is fixed there though: the proper text/clarification on what's being excluded or `www` is no longer being actually excluded.*

---

AFAIK the reason for such exclusion is performance-related issues ([WEB-25970](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-25970) and related).

---

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-27898#comment=27-2332673

> We automatically exclude 'www' directory for ionic projects.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-27898#comment=27-2332698

> As a workaround you can uncheck the option `File | Settings | Languages & Frameworks | JavaScript | PhoneGap/Cordova` --> "Automatically exclude 'platforms' directory".

Comment: Thank you very much for your so elaborate reply! But in my country, I can't open the youtrack.jetbrains.com links. :-(  I followed the instruction of unchecking the option of "Automatically exclude 'platforms' directory", but the problem remains the same. It's not solved. :-(

Comment: @Benson I see that you are in contact with JetBrains support (https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000463744-When-I-upgraded-WebStorm-to-2017-2-and-Ionic-plugin-to-3-5-0-it-seems-not-support-my-Ionic-v1-project-any-more-) .. then may provide better diagnosis after you give them more info (idea.log etc). The only other thing I may suggest right now -- try rolling back to 2017.1.x version for now

Comment: Thank you! The problem has been solved. There a second step to take: - right-click www folder, choose Mark directory as/Cancel exclusion. No need to roll back.:-)

Comment: @LazyOne I have added comment to the issue